# What's wrong with my django api code

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

https://ultimatedjango.com/blog/how-to-consume-rest-apis-with-django-python-reques/

I am following this guide and trying to change API to work with semrush.com site.

Problem is that unlike in tutorial they dont return data in JSON format but like this:

> domain;http://domain.com/fullUrl

I installed CSV render for rest framework and added this to settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # specifying the renderers
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_csv.renderers.CSVRenderer',
    ),
}
```

Here is serialaizer:

```
class SemrushSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SavedSemrush
```

And views.py:

```
def save_semrush(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SubmitSemrush(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            keyword = form.cleaned_data['keyword']            
            r = requests.get('http://api.semrush.com/?type=phrase_organic&key=' + settings.SEMRUSH_KEY + '&display_limit=10&export_columns=Dn,Ur&phrase=' + keyword + '&database=us')

            serializer = SemrushSerializer(data=r)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()


    else:
        form = SubmitSemrush()
```

Since after submitting form it just reload(without adding data to orm) I can only guess that either serializer is wrong for this data type or I managed to mess up simple code in views :)

Any ideas ?
cheers

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to instantiate the `SemrushSerializer` with a `Request` object.

You need to pass it JSON data.

```
r = requests.get(
    'http://api.semrush.com/?type=phrase_organic&key={key}&'
    'display_limit=10&export_columns=Dn,Ur&phrase={keyword}&'
    'database=us'.format(
    key=settings.SEMRUSH_KEY,
    keyword=keyword
)
json = r.json()
serializer = SemrushSerializer(data=json)
```